# Вывод прогресса асинхронной операции во вторичное окно

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, async-await

Есть метод, загружающий данные из файла. О своём прогрессе он сообщает через вызов события `OnFileLoad`

```
    public Task UploadDataAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ...
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath))
            {
                OnFileLoading?.Invoke($"Error while loading: Path is empty");
                ...
                throw new Exception("Path is emprty");
            }

            if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                OnFileLoading?.Invoke($"Error while loading: File not found");
                ...
                throw new Exception("File not found");
            }

            OnFileLoading?.Invoke($"Start loading from '{FilePath}'");
            ...
            OnFileLoading?.Invoke("Loaded first line");
            OnFileLoading?.Invoke("Loaded second line");
            ...
            OnFileLoading?.Invoke("Loaded n line");
            ...
            OnFileLoading?.Invoke("Loading completed");
        });            
    }
```

В классе главного окна есть обработчик события нажатия на кнопку "Открыть". В нём создаётся новое окно, в котором показывается прогресс загрузки данных из файла.

```
    public async void OpenFileClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var dataProvider = IocContainer.GetService<IDataProvider>();
            LoadingDataStatusWindow loadingDataStatusWindow = new LoadingDataStatusWindow();
            dataProvider.OnFileLoad = loadingDataStatusWindow.UpdateLoadingStatus;
            loadingDataStatusWindow.Show();
            dataProvider.FilePath = AppGlobalSettings.DataFilePath;
            await dataProvider.UploadDataAsync();
            items = dataProvider.CircuitItems;
            CircuitItemDataGrid.ItemsSource = dataProvider.CircuitItems;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LogUtility.LogError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Метод отображения прогресса окна `LoadingDataStatusWindow`:

```
    public void UpdateLoadingStatus(string currentRow)
    {            
        StatusTextBox.Text += currentRow + Environment.NewLine;          
    }
```

При попытке загрузить данные возникает ошибка, говорящая о том, что поток пытается обратиться к объекту, владельцем которого является другой поток.
Я пробовал починить это, сделав добавление текста в `StatusTextBox` через `Dispatcher`. Но это не помогло.

Как в данном случае можно организовать вывод прогресса во второе окно с асинхронной загрузкой данных, чтобы она не подвешивала GUI?

Comment: Делайте не через событие, а через `IProgress`. И так как вы ужасно образали код, не понятно, но 99%, что вам достаточно асинхронности, и вообще не нужен `Task.Run`. Покажите `UploadDataAsync` полностью.

Comment: @aepot Залил полностью код метода ```UploadDataAsync```

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH: Вы в `UploadDataAsync` обращаетесь к разделяемым переменным (например, `CircuitItems`, `FilePath`) без блокировки, это может быть не вполне верно.

Comment: Верние код в исходное состояние, так как в новой версии уже решен ваш изначальный вопрос, и ответ, опубликованный ниже, потерял смысл. Редактирование можно откатить в истории редактирования. А, так теперь видно, что это загрузка с диска, а зачем вам здесь поток? Оно слишком медленно грузит? Много строк? Попробуйте `AppendText` из комментария к ответу тогда.

Comment: Я откатил редактирование, уж простите.

Comment: @aepot Хотелось бы видеть вывод процесса по шагам. Если не использовать ```await/async``` GUI отмирает уже после окончательной загрузки.

Comment: Так вы все равно читаете пачкой, `async/await` здесь полностью в тему, я агрюсь именно на `Task.Run`. Можете использовать не `ReadAllLines`, а `StreamReader` и его `await ReadLineAsync`, читать файл построчно.

Comment: @aepot Получилось вот так: https://pastebin.com/QyhurZ8T

Comment: `while (!reader.EndOfStream)`, ну и `Delay` можно убрать, и не видно, убрали ли вы `Task.Run` :)

Comment: @aepot Его уж точно убрал :) ```Delay``` для большей отзывчивости окна, без него фризится. Спасибо!

Comment: Так вы прикутили `AppendText` вместо `.Text +=`? Быть может вам текстбокс и фризит.

Comment: @aepot Прикрутил, фризит окно без задержки

Comment: Там еще есть настоящий баг внутри `FileStream`, в асинхронном варианте он ненадолго блочит вызывающий поток. Все файловое API завязано на `FileStream`, следовательно и `StreamReader` от этого страдает. Майкрософты обещали починить, но вот пока не починили. Так что про `Delay` возможно вы и правы, но если вас устраивает оно в текущем виде, то можно и так оставить. Но еще одна фишка. Так как вы используете `IProgress`, можно попробовать сделать `await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)` и убрать `Delay`, может помочь.

Comment: Нашел ссылку, для информации - [баг с асинхронным файловым API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63217657/12888024).

Comment: Нашел патч, который использует Roslyn - C# компилятор. Попробуйте так `using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 1, useAsync: true))`, ну и уберите `Delay` для теста.

Comment: @aepot Фризит всё равно.

Comment: Ну тогда я иссяк. Окей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как совершенно верно заметил @aepot в комментариях, для сообщения о прогрессе операции используйте `Progress<T>`, он именно для этого и предназначен, и сам маршаллирует в нужный контекст.

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
public async void OpenFileClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    Progress<string> p = new(s => StatusTextBox.Text += s + Environment.NewLine);
    await UploadDataAsync(p);
    // ...
}
```

и соответственно

```
public async Task UploadDataAsync(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    // ...
    progress.Report($"Start loading from '{filePath}'");
    // ...
    progress.Report("Loaded first line");
    // ...
    progress.Report("Loaded second line");
    // ...
    progress.Report("Loaded n line");
    // ...
    progress.Report("Loading completed");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Помечу только что при использовании чисто асинхронного подхода, даже `IProgress` может не понадобиться, так как `await` по умолчанию восстанавливает контекст синхронизации. А потоки данных поддерживают `await WriteAsync` и т.п, так что можно без оберток в принципе обойтись. Например назначить `DataContext` дочернего окна на вьюмодель, и просто писать прогресс свойство этой вьюмодели, напрямую. В результате получится красиво вообще без спавна дополнительного потока.

Comment: @aepot: Ну если я правильно понял ТС, у него метод `UploadDataAsync` лежит глубоко в модели, и в принципе имеет право работать в любом потоке (например, может сбежать в отдельный поток из-за тяжёлых синхронных операций). Использование `IProgress<T>` мне кажется правильным не из-за технической стороны дела (а то я предпочёл бы Rx, `progressMessages.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(s => ...)` и возможно throttle), а семантически: `IProgress<T>` _специально предназначен_ для передачи сообщений о прогрессе, и у читателей кода будет меньше вопросов.

Comment: Кстати `Progress<string> p = new(s => StatusTextBox.AppendText(s + Environment.NewLine))` по производительности будет бодрее. :)

Comment: К вашему ответу у меня замечаний нет, он 100% правильный. И я всеми руками за `IProgress`, когда дело касается многопоточности. Это была просто ремарка.

Comment: @aepot: Ещё в коде ТС мне кажется подозрительным обращение к `OnFileLoad` из разных потоков без `lock`'а, но это отдельный вопрос.